# How to access a styles resources and retrieve an inner style that doesn't have a key

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a style for a stack panel which has a key, within the stack panel I have buttons which have a default style set via the stack panel's Style > Resources > Styles, for this reason the buttons style is not set via a key but instead is set as it is a child of the stack panel! I'm sure this is a little tricky to understand as it sure feels tricky to explain... here is the style code...

```
<Style x:Key="VerticalMenuPanel" TargetType="{x:Type StackPanel}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#115e9a" />

    <Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,0" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="13" />
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Calibri" />
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="27" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Border BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1">
                            <Border BorderBrush="#0160a2" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1.5">                                
                                <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                            </Border>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

So, basically, without getting into what I'm doing too much I require the need to change the style of the buttons within the stack panel based on certain events. In order to change the style I simply find the resource based on the style key! HOWEVER here is my problem, I can't reset the style back to the "default" style provided by the parent the "VerticalMenuPanel"s Style.Resources as I don't know how to retrieve the style without having a definitive key for it. The obvious thing to do would be to give the button style a key but then I would have to explicitly define the style for all of the buttons instead of the style being applied by default as it is a child of the stack panel!

The bottom line is how do I retrieve a style without a key from within a parent styles resources (programatically)? Obviously I can retrieve the parent style via its key.

I hope you understand the issue I am having, and please feel free to let me know if I can explain anything better, add more clarity or if you wish edit the post yourself :)

Comment: If you are doing this `Style`-switching in code-behind anyway, why not capture the `Button`'s current (default) `Style` before applying the alternate one? Then you'll have a reference to the default `Style` in a variable that you can use to switch back when appropriate.

Comment: @Jay that is the way I am doing it now, however I just felt it was a little bit of a cop out that won't meet all needs, good comment though, I'm just intrigued as to how I would do it via accessing the styles resources programatically :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the `Key` is not provided for a style, the `TargetType` becomes the key of that style. 
Here is an example:

```
<Grid x:Name="layoutRoot">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="100" />
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Button />
</Grid>
```

then in the code-behind you can retrieve the default style using the `Button` type as the resource Key:

```
Style buttonStyle = layoutRoot.FindResource(typeof(Button)) as Style;
```

Comment: +1 Exactly. It isn't always obvious in the XAML that one is in fact creating a dictionary, and you'll actually get a compilation error if you try to create two styles without keys and the same `TargetType`. If one has a reference to the `ResourceDictionary` itself, and know the style to be present, you can use `(Style)resourceDictionary[typeof(Button)]`.

Comment: thank you, exactly what I was looking for! Did the trick perfectly! +1 of course